# Mule Using MEL in Custom Business Events component

Tags: xml, xpath, mule, mel

Please advise how I need to use MEL in Custom Business Events component, Key Performance Indicators. According to MEL documentation, I need to use the expression ***#[xpath('//xpath/expression')]***

To get access to XML message I use the following expressions:

```
#[xpath('/Invoices/invoice')] 
#[xpath('//Invoices/invoice/invoiceHeader/InvoiceNo', message.payload)]
#[xpath('/Invoices/invoice/invoiceHeader/InvoiceNo/text()')]
```

and etc.
No results. Please help.

Comment: can you give us a sample of the xml?

Answer (score 0):

Use the following expression

`#[xpath://Invoices/invoice/invoiceHeader/InvoiceNo]`
example:`#[xpath:AnyXpathExpressoon]`